# Find a graph with an adjacency matrix consisting $0$

Tags: graph-theory

(okay, I'm not learning math in english, so please don't be harsh with me for not using the correct terminology here, but I hope you can understand my problem. also feel free to correct me)

Find a connected graph for every $n\geq4$ , for which is true, that his adjacency matrix on every power consists at least one(probably will consist 2) $0$. (where $n$ is the quantity of the vertices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the graph on vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with the edges $(1,2),(2,3),\dots,(n-1,n)$.  This is a [connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29) graph whose adjacency matrix is given by
$$
A_G = \pmatrix{
0&1&0 & 0&\cdots & 0\\
1&0&1&0&\cdots &0\\
0&1&0&1&\cdots &0\\
\,&&\ddots &\ddots& \ddots &\vdots\\
\\
&&&0&1&0
}
$$
The powers of this matrix will always contain a zero.

---

Suppose that $B$ is a matrix of the form
$$
B = \pmatrix{
0&b_{12}&0&b_{14}&\cdots\\
b_{12} & 0 & b_{23} & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & b_{23} & 0 & b_{34} & \cdots\\
b_{14} & 0 & b_{34} & 0 & \cdots\\
&\vdots&&\vdots & \ddots
}
$$
Then $A_G B$ will be a matrix of the form
$$
A_G B = C = \pmatrix{
c_{11}&0&c_{13}&0&\cdots\\
0&c_{22} & 0 & c_{24} & \cdots\\
c_{13} & 0 & c_{33} & 0 &\cdots\\
0&c_{24} & 0 & c_{34} & \cdots\\
&\vdots&&\vdots & \ddots
}
$$
Similarly, if $C$ is any matrix of the above form, then $A_G C$ will be a matrix with the form of $B$.

Using [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), you can conclude that ${A_G}^k$ will always have either the form of $B$ or $C$.

Comment: but why? could you explain or prove it?

Comment: I've added to my answer.  Let me know if what I said is unclear.

Comment: I feel quite dumb now, because I can't work out that induction. Could you give me a hint on how to prove the power of a matrix? (especially when you have 2 options to be the result)

Comment: You shouldn't feel dumb; my explanation wasn't particularly thorough.  If you still haven't figured it out, I'll clarify what I mean with that induction.

Comment: That is, I'll add to my answer once I get the chance.  Probably later today.

Comment: After thinking about it, I think N.S.'s argument regarding bipartite graphs is much easier to formulate for this case.  I would go for an explanation along those lines

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a connected bipartite graph with at least one vertex in each group.

If $u$ is a vertex, any walk from $u$ to $u$ has even length. This shows that tall the diagonal entries in $A^{2n+1}$ are $0$.

If $u,v$ are vertices in the two different group/color, any walk from $u$ to $v$ has odd length. This shows that the corresponding entry in the even powers of $A$ are all $0$.

To make it simple, let $v_1,v_2$ be vertices in the two different groups of the bi-partite graph. Then the $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ entries of $A^{2n+1}$ are all $0$, while the $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ entries of $A^{2n}$ are all $0$.

**P.S.** The answer provided by Omno is a tree, thus fit in this class of examples.